# unable to run ./pkb.py --help command i get series of ./pkb.py: line 58: import: command not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

New to perf benchmarking, python and ubuntu world :)
I'm unable run this command for doing some performance bench marking on Ubuntu OS. I tried running the command by navigating to the folder where i have cloned the perfkit tool. root@---:~/PerfKitBenchmarker/perfkitbenchmarker# ./pkb.py --help. when i do this

```
./pkb.py: line 58: import: command not found
./pkb.py: line 59: import: command not found
./pkb.py: line 60: import: command not found
./pkb.py: line 61: import: command not found
./pkb.py: line 62: import: command not found
./pkb.py: line 63: import: command not found
./pkb.py: line 64: import: command not found
./pkb.py: line 65: import: command not found
./pkb.py: line 66: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker.configs
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker.linux_benchmarks
from: can't read /var/mail/perfkitbenchmarker.publisher
./pkb.py: line 96: LOG_FILE_NAME: command not found
./pkb.py: line 97: REQUIRED_INFO: command not found
./pkb.py: line 98: syntax error near unexpected token (' ./pkb.py: line 98:REQUIRED_EXECUTABLES = frozenset(['ssh', 'ssh-keygen', 'scp', 'openssl'])'
```

I also tried with command but getting same import error:

python ./pkb.py --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./pkb.py", line 68, in 
from perfkitbenchmarker import archive
ImportError: No module named perfkitbenchmarker

Can some one help me with the issue?

Thanks,
Goutham

Comment: Have you tried using python pkb.py ? You could also check what's the default location of the python binary (usually in `/usr/sbin/python`) and be sure that your pkb.py is including something like `#!/usr/bin/python` on the first line of the script.